# More efficient way to write foreach loops in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-4

Currently, my application uses quite a few `foreach` loops, to iterate through an array pulled through the database.

In order for the user to access the page, whether they have 0,1 or 100 results, I have to use three `IF` statements, to stop the foreach loop from breaking. This check is solely for 0 and 1 results, anything greater works fine.

I imagine I'll have several more pages to iterate through certain database results, and surely using 3 IF statements isn't the most efficient way?

**An example:**

*Controller:*

```
public function getArchived()
    {
        $alert = Alert::with('location')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                                        ->onlyTrashed()
                                        ->first();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.alert.archived', 
                                             array('alert' => $alert));
    }
```

View (shortened):

```
@if((count($alert) > 1)
    @foreach($alert->alerts as $alert)
        {{ $alert->id }}
    @endforeach
@elseif ((count($alert) > 0)
        {{ $alert->id }}    
@else
    <p>You have no results</p>
@endif
```

Is there a check one can do on the controller prior to sending the array to the view? Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You use the `first()`-Function. You always get only one result, didnt you? Please show more code!

Comment: What further code do you need to see @Fuzzyma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you don't need to do those checks. You are using `first()` to get a single object.

I think what you want to do is use `get()` instead to get a collection of archived Alerts.

```
$alerts = Alert::with('location')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                                    ->onlyTrashed()
                                    ->get();
$this->layout->content = View::make('agents.alert.archived', 
                                         array('alerts' => $alerts));
```

Now you know you will be receiving a Collection that can be iterated.

```
    @foreach($alerts as $alert)
        {{ $alert->id }}
    @endforeach
    @if($alerts->empty())
        No Records
    @endif
```

**Update:**

In Laravel 4.2, Blade now supports this type of syntax:

```
@forelse($whole as $piece)
    {{ $piece->something }}
@empty
    No Records
@endforelse
```

Comment: Hi @Drew Lewis, thank you for your reply. This makes perfect sense. The error now appears to be when accessing a relationship within the foreach loop, for example: {{ $alert->location->address_1}}. I know this is correct as it did work on the previous ->first() incorrect statement. An `alert` belongs to `location`.

Comment: ErrorException - Trying to get property of non-object, and it's on this line inside the `foreach` - `{{ $alert->location->address_1}}`.

Comment: @Svengali make sure every one of those alerts has a location

Comment: They all definitely do. Like I said, when I was using ->first(), this successfully retrieved the locations for each of the alerts, I'm not sure why it would change now?

Comment: It's also the same now with trying to access `messages` relating to the alert. Each message belongs to an alert (by foreign key). `$alert->messages->count()` now also fails.

Comment: perhaps you could post your models to  [Laravel Pastebin](http://laravel.io/bin) and paste back the url to the paste

Comment: Sorry lagbox, it's now working fine, a typo on my part. Many thanks for your help.